# Dialog box name

Tags: vb.net

Does any one know the dialog below like a lower third?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the [**Component Tray**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e06hs424.aspx).

> Non-visual components added to the Windows Forms Designer are placed on the **Component Tray**, located below the design surface, so that they are easily accessible without cluttering the visual design space.